# Assembly MASM save dynamic array on memory correct way

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, msvcrt

Hello I want to save in memory an array of length and values defined by the users.
Actually I'm storing the values inserted at "[ebp+8+esi*4]", so after the function arguments. Is that correct or what should I do?
I though that local variables should placed at memory address below esp, so make space for local variables by decrementing esp.
But I can't dynamically decrement "esp", so how should I do?

This is the code:

```
.686
.xmm
.model flat, C
OPTION CaseMap:None

include ../masm32/libs/windows.inc
include ../masm32/libs/kernel32.inc
include ../masm32/libs/user32.inc
include ../masm32/libs/msvcrt.inc
include ../masm32/libs/masm32.inc

EXTERN printf:PROC
EXTERN scanf:PROC

.data
    str_insert_array_length db  "Insert Array Length: ",0
    str_insert_value    db  10,"Insert Value: ",0
    str_input_format    db  "%d",0
    str_format_print db "%d",10,0

    input_length   DWORD    0
    input_value    DWORD    0

.code

main PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

    push offset str_insert_array_length
    call printf
    add esp,4

    push offset input_length
    push offset str_input_format
    call scanf
    add esp,8
    
mov edi,[input_length]

array_input:
    push offset str_insert_value
    call printf
    add esp,4

    push offset input_value
    push offset str_format
    call scanf
    add esp,8

    mov eax, [input_value]
    push eax

    dec edi
    jnz array_input

    mov edi,[input_length]
    xor esi,esi

    push offset str_print_array
    call printf
    add esp,4


print_array:
    mov edx,[esp+4*esi]
    push edx
    push offset str_format_print
    call printf
    add esp,8
    inc esi
    dec edi
    jnz print_array


    pop ebp
    invoke ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
    end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically decrement sp.  Just use a subtract instruction, like `sub esp, eax`, where you have established the amount of dynamic decrement in `eax`.  If you do that the the new array starts at the address in `esp`.

The problem is that you can't compute the decrement amount until you know how many items are being input.

So. If you don't know how many items there will be until the user says to stop, then you can push individual items onto the stack as the are entered, but the resulting array will have the elements backward in nemory order — so, you can later either reverse them in place with a simple loop, or instead just choose to work with the backwards order, if the rest of the program is not too complicated.

Using the stack this way is further complicated by alignment requirements.  First the alignment for x86 is larger than an single integer, and so padding on the stack will be sometimes required, before function calling, such as `printf`.  Second, if the array's element size is smaller than an integer, e.g. a byte or 8-bit character, pushing that will introduce padding to full integer size, so the items on the stack would not only be backwards in memory but also spread out with padding.

Because of those complications of the stack, other solutions are often used: fixed size buffer, or, expandable array.

For fixed sized buffer, simply allocate more than ever needed.  So, allocate space for 128 elements (satisfies alignment).  Can simply stop the program with error message if more than that encountered.

For exandable array, to add element, allocate more storage and copy existing into the larger new storage.  Various techniques to reduce copies as speed-space tradeoff.  This approach would usually use heap memory instead of stack.

Comment: You should first round EAX up to a multiple of 4, or `and esp, -4` *after* `sub esp, eax`.  (Or multiple of 16 if you're maintaining 16-byte stack alignment.)  You don't want the stack pointer to be misaligned for any functions you call after this.

Comment: Hello Erik thank you for your answer, but I didn't get the last part of your answer. What do you mean with "Use heap memory instead of stack?", heap memory isn't used for defined variables? So a fixed sized array? How can I define an array variable (so it must have a fixed size) and expand it without overwriting existing memory that belong to other things?

Comment: You wouldn't put a local variable in the heap, but you can reference heap data from a local variable.

Comment: Hello @ErikEidt thanks for your answer, but how can I reference heap data from a local variable? I'm not understanding this part. I did some courses about Assembly but in none of these courses they did anything similar :/ Do you have any code reference about that to look?